# memory allocation in Base *p = new Derived()

Tags: c++

If I have a `class Base { };` and `class Derived : public Base { };`, and when I do the following:

```
Base* p = new Derived();
```

How much memory is allocated to `p`?

Comment: Presumably `sizeof(Derived)` ?

Comment: p is a pointer. new Derived create an object of type Derived. so it is sizeof(Derived)

Comment: Is this homework? (In C++, an expression does not change meaning based on what you assign it to.)

Comment: Depends. If this throws a `bad_alloc` then 0 bytes have been allocated.

Comment: Are you asking how much memory is allocated to `p` itself? Or are you asking how much memory is allocated for the `new Derived` object that `p` points to? If the former, `sizeof(Base*)`. If the latter, at least `sizeof(Derived)`.

Answer (score 8):

As much as is needed to store `Derived` object.

You can get number of bytes with `sizeof(Derived)`.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(Derived)` at the address pointed by `p`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `p` will point to the start of a memory chunk, containing a `Derived` object. Therefor the allocated size will be `sizeof(Derived)`, with a pointer of type `Base` pointing there.

Answer (score 0):

as i remember the total size is: sizeof(Derived). if you mark a method as `virtual` sizeof() takes in account also 4 byte for a pointer to the vtable.

so if you have

```
class Base {
int a;
}
```

`sizeof(Derived)` will be 4

```
class Base {
int a;
virtual foo();
}
```

`sizeof(Derived)` will be 8

Comment: 4 bytes overhead is common, but other values also occur. C++ programmers don't need to care. `sizeof(Derived)` already includes any overhead needed for virtual functions.